# Process columns in chunks and write to csv

Tags: python, pandas, csv, chunks

I have a dataframe with around 2.5 million rows and more than 7000 columns(all categorical).
I iterate through each column, dummy the variables and do some processing and concatenate to a final dataframe.

The code is below:

```
cat_count = 0
df_final = pd.DataFrame()

for each_col in cat_cols: 

    df_temp = pd.DataFrame()
    df_single_col_data = df_data[[each_col]]
    cat_count += 1
    # Calculate uniques and nulls in each column to display in log file.    
    uniques_in_column = len(df_single_col_data[each_col].unique())
    nulls_in_column = df_single_col_data.isnull().sum()

    print('%s has %s unique values and %s null values' %(each_col,uniques_in_column,nulls_in_column[0]))


    #Convert into dummies 
    df_categorical_attribute = pd.get_dummies(df_single_col_data[each_col].astype(str), dummy_na=True, prefix=each_col)
    df_categorical_attribute = df_categorical_attribute.loc[:, df_categorical_attribute.var() != 0.0]# Drop columns with 0 variance.

    #//// Some data processing code://///

    df_final = pd.concat([df_final,df_categorical_attribute],axis = 1)
    print ('*'*10 + "\n Variable number %s processed!" %(cat_count))



# Write the final dataframe to a csv
df_final.to_csv('cat_processed.csv')
```

However, for such large data, df_final hogs up upto 75% of the memory on the server and I would like to reduce the memory footprint of this piece of code.

So what I am thinking is, I will process till the 300th column, write the results to csv. Then again process the next 300 columns, open the csv , write to it and close.
In that way, df_final at a time will hold the results of only 300 columns.
Can someone please help me with this?
Or, if there is any better way to deal with the issue, I would like to implement that too.

Below is some sample data to replicate:
df_data

```
  rev_m1_Transform  ov_m1_Transform ana_m1_Transform    oov_m1_Transform
    0_to_12.95          34.95_to_846.4  65_to_74.95         64.9_to_1239.51
    13.95_to_116.55     14.95_to_19.95  45.05_to_60.05      34.9_to_39.95
    12.95_to_13.95      19.95_to_29.95  89.95_to_9491.36    54.95_to_59.95
    0_to_12.95          0_to_14.95      0_to_29.949999      64.9_to_1239.51
    0_to_12.95          19.95_to_29.95  74.95_to_83.9       54.95_to_59.95
    0_to_12.95          0_to_14.95      0_to_29.9499        0_to_34.9
    0_to_12.95          14.95_to_19.95  45.05_to_60.05      39.95_to_44.9
    0_to_12.95          0_to_14.95      0_to_29.949         0_to_34.9
    0_to_12.95          19.95_to_29.95  89.95_to_9491.36    54.95_to_59.95
```

cat_cols is a list with all the column names in df_data
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going for columns go for a **chunk of rows**, then apply processing step on all the columns. For example:

```
CHUNKSIZE = 1000

for chunk in pd.read_csv("filename.csv", chunksize=CHUNKSIZE):
    #Apply processing steps here 
    processed = process(chunk)

    processed.to_csv("final.csv", mode="a")
```

Use CHUNKSIZE according to your physical memory size (RAM).

Comment: the filename.csv does not exist since it is created after all the processing is done. And I need to read in all the rows since I am finding some metrics like skewness, kurtosis for each column.Thanks!